# Disable all Gnome Notifications (Gnome 3.20.4)

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

How can I disable all popup notifications in **Gnome 3.20.4?**

I'm on **Ubuntu 16.10 (64bit).**

I have tried selecting "off" in the "Notification Banners"; that didn't work.

I also manually switched each application to "off", that also didn't work.

[image: didn't work]

I still get these popups, which I really don't like:

[image]

How can I make these popup go away?

Answer (score 3):

Install `dconf-editor`, run it, and go to

```
org.gnome.desktop.notifications
```

here is a large string there that has all the applications that will receive the gnome notification. If the app has its own notifications you can enable them in the app and disable the system notification.

---

I had to go into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autrunManager.js` and comment out the following line:

```
Main.messageTray.add(this);
```

For me it was on line 546, but who knows how it scoots around in other versions of gnome (cause it's constantly changing).

If the above methods do not work the [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409996) out. but don't delete the line as suggested in answer just comment (#) it.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked for me. All show as "false" in dconf-editor, that .js file doesn't exist on my computer (or anything like it in that tree that I could find), and the link you provided also doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Can you update your question with gnome version? I'll try to research more

Comment: @JoshuaD how foolish of me, it was already written in question,.

Comment: Don't sweat it! I appreciate the help. <3

Comment: Moreover, on the key *application-children*:  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.notifications application-children`